# Посчитать количество символов в каждой новой строке

Tags: c, строки

Стоит задача: Написать программу, которая для введённой строки определяет количество слов и выводит каждое слово на отдельной строке и его длину. Я написал программу которая считает слова и переводит на новую строку каждую . как  реализовать подсчет длины символов в каждой строке ? Знаю что через strlen, а где именно использовать эту функцию не понимаю.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define IN 1//внутри слова
#define OUT 0// снаружи слова 
#define PR printf


int main()
{

    char buf[256] = { 0 };
    int flag = OUT;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int word = 0;
    PR("Enter a line ,please:\n");
    fgets(buf, 512, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = ' ';//удаление \n
    while (buf[i])
    {

            if (buf[i] != ' ' && flag == OUT)
            {
                count++;
                flag = IN;//вошли в слово
                putchar(buf[i]);
            }
            else if (buf[i] != ' '&& flag == IN)
            {
                putchar(buf[i]);//внутри слова
            }
            else if (buf[i] == ' '&& flag == IN)
            {
                flag = OUT;//вышли из слова
                putchar('\n');
            }
            i++;    

    }
    putchar('\n');

    PR("%d words\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: заведите счетчик, который обнуляйте при входе в слово, увеличивайте внутри слова и выводите при выходе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int countSymbolsCurrentWord = 0;    
while (buf[i])
    {

        if (buf[i] != ' ' && flag == OUT)
        {
            count++;
            flag = IN;//вошли в слово
            putchar(buf[i]);
        }
        else if (buf[i] != ' '&& flag == IN)
        {
            putchar(buf[i]);//внутри слова
            countSymbolsCurrentWord++; // увеличиваем кол-во символов на один
        }
        else if (buf[i] == ' '&& flag == IN)
        {
            printf("%s %d\n", " ;count symbols: ", countSymbolsCurrentWord); // выводим на экран + переходим на новую строку
            countSymbolsCurrentWord = 0; // и обнуляем, т.к. количество символов в слове получено 
            flag = OUT;//вышли из слова
        }
        i++;    

}
```